# Ошибка преобразования в строку при компиляции

Tags: java, строки, компиляция

Привожу часть программы, вызывающую ошибку компиляции, причину которой найти не могу

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> value,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        int countofparams=0;

        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream(
                "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/countofparams.txt");
        DataInputStream input1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input1));
        String result1=br1.readLine();
        countofparams=Integer.parseInt(result1);
        input1.close();
        fstream1.close();

        String line = key.toString();
        ArrayList<String> ProcessedTherms = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizerforprocessedterms = new StringTokenizer(line, "\n");
        while (tokenizerforprocessedterms.hasMoreTokens()) {
            ProcessedTherms.add(tokenizerforprocessedterms.nextToken());
        }

        ArrayList<String> CountOfThermsAndIds = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        ArrayList<Integer> CountOfTherms = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> Ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (value.hasNext())
        {
            String valueline=value.next().get().toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(valueline, " ");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
            {
                CountOfThermsAndIds.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }               
        }
```

В результате компиляции получаю ошибку

```
/partrain/src/ParallelTraining.java:252: error: cannot find symbol
                String valueline=value.next().get().toString();
                                             ^
  symbol:   method get()
  location: class Text
```

Помогите утсранить ошибку.

Comment: постарайтесь писать код самостоятельно, а не перепечатывать листинги из книги. ибо, порочная практика.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А что непонятного?

`value` имеет тип `Iterator<Text>`. Значит, [`value.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) имеет тип `Text`. У класса [`Text`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html) нету метода `get()`.

Comment: @VladD может вы и правы, но выражение

    value.next().get()
взято с книги по `hadoop`. Хотя возможно конечно и ошбка в книге.

Comment: Вполне возможно, в любом случае, спор тут, судя по всему, не между мной и книгой, а между компилятором и книгой.